# Determing the lexical category of a word based on the affixes attached

Tags: grammar, suffixes, prefixes, linguistics, affixes

I am currently taking a Linguistics course and am learning about affixes. Through reading the textbook and following the lectures, I have realized that certain prefixes and suffixes are attached to words that belong only to a certain lexical category. For instance, derivational affixes are attached to nouns and certain suffixes are only attached to adjectives.

I was just hoping to know if anyone here could provide any sources that I can use to learn more about this. Perhaps a list that contains various affixes and which category of words they are generally morphed with. It is just a little overwhelming to figure what the lexical category of a word is by just following the affixes given that different combination will give different results.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Requests for sources of information belong on [Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a list of affixes, there's Wiktionary: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_suffixes
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_prefixes
You will be most interested in the **productive** affixes, of which there are [37 prefixes](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_productive_prefixes) and [36 suffixes](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_productive_suffixes) listed on Wiktionary.

Regarding the [derivational affixes](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_derivational_suffixes), you said that that they're attached to nouns. That's not necessarily true. A derivational affix is any affix that creates a new word from a different word.

I don't know about other resources regarding linguistics and affixes. Personally I read most things on Wikipedia. Since you are in a linguistics course you might want something more scholarly, and you might get better recommendations on the [Linguistics Stack Exchange](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Almost all English morphology is derivational. There are only 8 [inflectional affixes, all suffixes](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Inflection.pdf)  (9 if you count the infinitive zero suffix + _be_).

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer has definitely helped me out.